# Site to ask about visas, immigration, asylum seeking

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a site that I can ask about topics regarding bringing someone to the US?

Both my wife and I are US Citizens with passports, etc.  My mother-in-law is in Iraq and I contacted a lawyer regarding bringing her here.  She mentioned two methods. One is to get her through the UN (a long process) and the other is through application/visa which would allow her to apply for asylum or apply for a visa (not sure which).  The issue is the lawyer is very expensive. We are talking about tens of thousands of dollars.  We don't want to go through the United Nations because the process could take over 15 years...So I want to bring her here using the second method.

On the other hand she mentioned you have the right to bring her which means I should be able to do this without a lawyer, so I wanted to ask questions to find out what process I need to take.

Is there a site I can ask such questions.

Comment: THanks @random - that title is much better than what I originally had.

Comment: Looks halfway between [travel.se] and [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like either [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) or [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/). I'd try Expatriates first, sounds closer to what you want. Make sure to read their [help center](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking to see if your question is really on-topic there.

Answer (score 8):

I am a mod at expats. Seems on topic for us. I think it would probably be better as multiple questions as opposed to a single huge question.

Comment: Thanks that really helped, those folks are awesome.